# Rstudio system2() command being sent to wrong terminal

Tags: r, ubuntu, terminal, rstudio

**EDIT: This has been resolved by using the terminalsend command in the rstudioapi package instead of system2.**

I'd like to use Rstudio to run a command (2 if you include cd) in my Ubuntu partition. I've successfully opened the Ubuntu command line in Rstudio by changing the Terminal options to open in bash. I am using system2() to send commands to the terminal. Each command works in the Terminal if I run them in the terminal themselves, but running them from the notebook using system2() sends them to a Windows command line, which does not work. I am hoping that I can run the code like so:

```
system2("cd scriptfolder")
system2("./ script -parameters -filepathway -etc", stdout = TRUE)
```

Running Windows 10 Home, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and Rstudio 1.4.1717. Apologies for lack of reproducible code.

EDIT: Upon further inspection Rstudio is not sending these commands to the "correct" terminal. I have a Bash terminal open in Rstudio which is on my Linux partition, but the system2() commands from the R notebook are being sent to the Windows side.

Chaining the commands together gives a "not found" error, as does the second command when I run them separately. I have a folder in my Windows partition with a name identical to the scriptfolder, which is why the cd command works.

Comment: maybe you have to chain them... `system2("cd scriptfolder && ./ script -parameters -filepathway -etc", stdout = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful to clarify that the problem was not with the cd command not being remembered, but the command being sent to the wrong terminal.